# Application not getting deployed on Blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry, simulator, blackberry-os-v4.5

I am tried deploying .cod,.alx.jar files on blackberry simulator 8100;the application is not getting deployed on phone.I am using Blackberry plugin for Eclipse.
How can I solve this issue?

Please help

---

**Update**

Hi,
Thanks for your reply.
I am trying to run the application the way you suggested.

Do I need to setup new run configuration every time I run any project?

What should be default value for build configuration ? [Debug,Private,or Release]

Comment: Not to offend, but did you check in the download folder in the simulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copying the .cod files into the simulator's directory (where all the other .cod files are) and restarting the simulator will work.

Probably though you want to automatically deploy from Eclipse. If this isn't working for you, there are a couple of things to check:

Check that the project has been activated for BlackBerry - from the right-click menu for the project, make sure that Activate For BlackBerry is checked.

If that's already checked (as it is by default when you create a new BB project), then sometimes explicitly building the project will do the trick: From the Project menu, choose Build Active BlackBerry Simulation

EDIT: In response to some comments below I thought of something else.  The configuration you choose may have something to do with your problems (BlackBerry -> Build Configurations).  The configuration in the JDE Plug-in doesn't affect the code generated, but it *does* affect which projects are activated for BlackBerry.  If you switch configurations, your project may become un-activated.
Since it doesn't affect the code, I usually just pick one configuration and stick with it throughout debugging and release.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your solution.
I marked "Activate for Blackberry". It was not already checked.

Then I tried running the application,still the application didnt run.

Then just for check, I tried changing application type to Midlet and saved the settings.Exited the wizard,Again changed to CLDC app. and built the app.
I dont know how, but it worked.Application ran successfully on simulator.

It just worked.I didnt find what actually would have happened.
:)

Comment: In response to your EDIT, I had set BlackBerry -> Build Configurations... -> Debug, in the hope that I would get more debug output from the simluation.  As you say, this seems to stop my project building.  To 'fix' that, pick BlackBerry -> Build Configurations... -> Edit..., then makes sure all your projects are selected.  After another rebuild and launching the simulator my application was updated.  I wonder how long this will continue working...

Answer (score 6):

You might be missing 'jar' in your PATH. If so, the eclipse BB plugin silently fails and your application won't be pushed to your simulator plugin directory. To see this failure within eclipse, choose 'Project > Build Active BlackBerry Simulation'.

If you don't have jar in your path, then you will see:

```
I/O Error: Cannot run program "jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified rapc executed for the project
```

So, if your JDK is here:

```
C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin
```

Then append it to your system environment's PATH variable, then re-run 'Build Active BlackBerry Simulation' and you should see:

```
rapc executed for the project [YOUR PROJECT]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1) If you have any build errors then the application won't deploy to the Simulator.  The Eclipse compiler (that underlines compile errors in red) is different to the "rapc" one that creates the binary for the Simulator.  I have heard of situations where the Eclipse build seems to work, but the rapc compile fails - check the Console for the detailed rapc output (this might not look like a normal Eclipse build error).

2) In the Eclipse menu, open BlackBerry -> Configure BlackBerry Workspace.

Under BlackBerry JDE choose Code Signing and make sure the three RIM checkboxes are selected.  I had compile errors when these weren't selected.

Under BlackBerry JDE choose Installed Components.  Choose to use the Component Package 4.7.0 as I have heard of problems with the 4.5.0 Simulator.

You should delete all these extra answers you posted, or you might get downvotes - they should be comments instead of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your simulator is set up to clean the file system / configuration before launching the simulator. Simulators can be set up like this. If you deactivate it, the application should not disappear.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, there is another possibility for this issue.  Check your workbench project directory (folder) for a ProjectName.err file.  This may provide a clue as to why your build is silently failing and thus not deploying.  In my case, it was an "Error!907", a new icon I added to my project was too big. There was absolutely no other indications in Eclipse 3.4.1 that there was a problem in my build.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran through the same kind of problem : project compiled fine but didn't deploy on any device or on any simulator, even though the debugger said it was attached !
The problem came from a .zip file that was located in the ./src directory of the project, deleting or moving it somewhere else resolved this case.
I wish I hadn't spend 2+ hours on such a stupid problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you have to do the "generate ALX" option from right clicking the project menu as well or it won't deploy, at least it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem again and none of answers posted here worked for me.

I played around and finally made it work. The problem was that the output file name **contained a hyphen ('-')**. Changing this name in the Build section of BlackBerry app descriptor did the trick.

I mean, how stupid a developer must be to slip that kind of bug. No error reported and why reject the names with hyphens in the first place? Give me back my two hours RIM "developers"!

Comment: I didn't see this bug. I am using the latest version of the BlackBerry plug-in for Eclipse (as of the time of writing this comment), and I do have a project whose output file name contains hyphens. It's running correctly; I don't see any problems caused by that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was using '**ü**' character in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem today, but with a MIDlet project. It turned out to be that I forgot to specify the "Name of main MIDlet class" in the BlackBerry Application Descriptor (BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml). Once I specified it the application appeared on the simulator correctly.