# Blackberry - app not showing up on the simulator

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, rim-4.6

I am using the Blackberry SDK 4.6 eclipse plugin to create applications. My applications were running fine till some time back when testing on the simulator. Then I ran the clear.bat to remove all applications I had added.

Now whenever I try to compile and run my app from eclipse, it does not show up in the simulator. I tried creating the whole project again but still the same result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788442/application-not-getting-deployed-on-blackberry-simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the /clear-flash command in the batch file that launches the simulator, this will reset the sim back to it's 'default' mode.

Are the .cod files being put into the same folder as the simulator?  Is the simulator opening up when you run from Eclipse?