# Eclipse (Blackberry JDE 4.6.1) fails deploying the application on the simulator

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-jde, .cod-file

this is the message I receive when I try to build my applicaion.

> ```
> ..\HBB\HBB.rapc -sourceroot=C:\ws\HBB\src @HBB_build.files
> ```

```
I/O Error: C:\ws\HBB\HBB.cod (The system cannot find the file specified)
rapc executed for the project HBB
```

the project is currently set as "Active for Blackberry" and all the other option are set as defined here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788442/application-not-getting-deployed-on-blackberry-simulator)

why the .cod file is not created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that sometimes eclipse (or the blackberry plugin) becomes out-of-sync with the filesystem so it appears to eclipse that the file is there, but in actuality it's not. My workaround for this issue is to delete the output directory and compile again. This seems to force the file to be rebuilt before it is referenced in the build process.