# Blackberry simulator needs to run every time run the app

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, simulator

I have configured Blackberry plugin in eclipse

```
a) Eclipse with blackberry plugin pre-loaded - 32 bit   
b) JDK 1.7 -
   32 bit   
c) Blackberry simulators 
d) jre 7
```

It is configured properly and app is running fine when i run the app first time.

Later if i made any changes in code and run the app again then loader appears on the simulator which is running but nothing happens. (loader got dismiss as well)

App simply wont run until i close the simulator and relaunch it.

Please help regarding this. Initially it is working fine on 32 bit machine

Comment: I've had this issue before, but didn't go into too much depth to fix it since I rather test on the devices. This may help though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788442/application-not-getting-deployed-on-blackberry-simulator

Comment: Yes but AFAIK it is bit time consuming to run the app on device everytime. Running the app on simulator is just a matter of few seconds.